# EF Code First Drop Database?

Tags: entity-framework

I want to use EF code first migrations to create my models in the database. However, the database I will use already exists and is shared by other applications. My question is:

Do migrations erase the database? That would be a disaster!
Do migrations erase anything at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Q :** Do migrations erase the database ?

**A :** No.You can do that without erasing it.

You have to do it as shown below on the **Package Manger console**.

**Step 1 :**

```
PM > Add-Migration InitialCreate –IgnoreChanges
```

Above command will create an empty migration with the current model as a snapshot.

**Step 2 :**

```
PM > Update-Database
```

Above command will apply the `InitialCreate` migration to the database. Hence the actual migration doesn’t contain any changes, it will add a row to the `__MigrationsHistory` table indicating that this migration has already been applied.

You can read more about it here : [**CF Migrations with an existing database**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn579398(v=vs.113).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do in this situation is create a migration to the existing database and then remove everything out of the Up and Down methods and run the update. This way your code first migrations will be up to date with whats currently in the database so any new schema changes that are made will be the only thing picked up by adding a second migration.